# Accessing an array inside of a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am using an AJAX GET request to obtain a javascript object.  Serverside, it is a hashmap that consists of a String and an ArrayList of Strings.  Inside the success function, I am using a for-in loop to access the data that looks like this at the moment (console.log for debugging):

```
for (var key in content) {
    if (content.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }           
 }
```

It displays the key correctly, but how can I access the array associated with it?  If I output the response to the console, it shows "KEY: Array[13]", and I can expand it to see the contents of the array.

Comment: @BrianGerhards JSFiddle is a great tool, however this was simply me not knowing syntax.  Two others were able to help me within minutes, so I do not think a JSFiddle is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var key in content) {
    if (content.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(content[key]);
    }           
 }
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb now.  Even saw this in another question, just didn't think it was applicable to my situation.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

most conventional way

```
 for(var i=0 ; i< key.length ; i++ )
    console.log(key[i]);
```